# React Native App on android build says "Unable to load script from assets'index.android.bundle' " requires a system restart

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Whenever **I run the application on the android phone** I get this type of error shown in the image

[image]

What I have tried so far is:

regarding packager or metro bundle,I have to shut down my laptop for 10 minutes or some time then the error vanishes, why it is happening? I am using *ubuntu as my operating system*.

even when it's an error in code and metro bundle error shows up; still the same issue pops up.

I have tried command  killing the adb server and restarting the metro too! but nothing good happens.

'yarn start/npm start' etc but it makes nothing for me except another error

on running

```
yarn start/npm start
```

i get this error

[image]

This error will be no more if I shut down the system & start after sometime & the project works fine! after it until the next error arrives.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1088794 I think this might be related to your issue. I think you need to increase the number of max_user_watches

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain it further plz

Comment: No. That answer explains it better than I could. Although they aren’t dealing with react native it looks like your problem and the one they are having is similar. The solution there may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you installed some packages through super user privileges, so when you run your project, some files deny Access.

Moreover please check your react and react-native versions and update them to the latest one. To upgrade to latest version run this command
 `$ npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade` then `$ react-native-git-upgrade`

Or open package.json and change versions of react to  "16.6.3" and react-native to "0.57.8".